# What is the appropriate location for a custom script?

Tags: linux, redhat, best-practices

I wrote a script for my Red Hat server that aggregates some system info and shoots it off in an email. **What is the appropriate location to place that script?**

Right now it is in my `/home/jeff` directory but I doubt that is a very good practice. I tried moving it to `/usr/bin/` but my permissions were denied and that scared me off from forcing it to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It it's personal script, I think it's better to keep it in `~/bin/`. If it's system-wide (will be used by other users and/or services), I'd agree with @Zoredache: `/usr/local/bin/` will be a good place.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a really minor script you could drop it `/etc`, there are already many scripts there that configure core functionality of your system.  The location suggested by the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) would be [/usr/local/{bin|sbin}](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY).

Answer (score 1):

Custom items should be segregated in an intelligent way so that drastic work on the system wil not inadvertently affect them. I favor using "opt" directories (i.e. /opt , /etc/opt, var/opt/log , etc.) and placing components appropriately within them, generally in further subdirectories associated with the organization or application (i.e. /etc/opt/gnome for example) .

Comment: The way I read the FHS suggest that `/opt` should be used for 3rd party software not your internal tools.  Not saying that it would really harm anything if you have good documentation though.